# hibernate and datawarehouse

Tags: hibernate, orm, data-warehouse

is it logical to use an ORM layer like hibernate for huge data. 
We have a non-relational database with 100T data. Which is the best way
to access data from a web application?

JDBC, Hibernate, ... ?

Comment: What's the purpose of connecting to the data warehouse? If you need to create reports, you'll be better served by looking at a robust business intelligence solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, Hibernate is a poor fit to access data from the data warehouse. Hibernate is best suited to the tasks that need one-to-one representation of the database records as objects. Data warehouse data is usually too large to do that.

Hibernate certainly can be used in some niches of such application. For example, in our web-based data warehouses hibernate is used to write and represent in the web application statistics about the ETL processes. It can also be used in conjunction with the dimension data when a user selects criteria for their reporting.

For the reporting itself you can use JDBC, but your best bet would be a dedicated reporting library or tool.